# Can someone show me why my variables work outside of a functions and not inside a function

Tags: javascript

Im studying JavaScript,

I can make variables, and they work. However when I place them in side a function they dont work..? why? I recieve the answer ( 10 0 undefined)

```js
var totalPeople = 3;
var totalApples = 30;

function tree(totalApples, totalPeople) {
  const shareApples = totalApples / totalPeople;
  const moduloApples = totalApples % totalPeople;

  const output = shareApples;

  console.log(output + " " + moduloApples);
}

console.log(tree(totalApples, totalPeople));
```

Comment: Define "not work". What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: The arguments are shadowing the outer variables, so `totalApples` etc values will be determined by how the function is called, not by the value in the outer scope

Comment: Google JavaScript scope. Basically variables declared inside a function are only known inside the function. Variables declared outside a function can be thought of as global. Make sure you understand passing by value and pass by reference